# Are there any real file types with non-ASCII file extensions

Tags: file-extension, non-ascii-characters

`.txt`
`.pdf`
`.exe`

etc...

Obviously, you *can* create a file with any extension you want.

But are there any **real** examples of files legitimately having non-ASCII file extensions?

Comment: Apparent there are non-ASCII domains now: https://www.dynadot.com/community/help/question/what-is-ascii .भारत (used for websites in India)
.网络 (the .NET equivalent in China)
.קום (the .COM equivalent in Hebrew)

Comment: Please define your understanding of "legitimately"

Comment: Not a troll extension, e.g. something that includes non-ASCII characters, just for the sake of doing so. (c.f. emojli a messaging app that exclusively uses emoji ... but only exists for the sake of the concept existing)

Answer (score 0):

[Mojo](https://docs.modular.com/mojo) (a new programming language currently in development) uses the  character as an extension, e.g. hello_world. (though you can also use `.mojo`)